# Simulate Push Notification in UITest

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, xctest

We would like to test the receiving of push notifications (while the app is active) in an UITest. The goto solution with sending real push notifications sounds a bit like an overkill (and only works on a real device): see http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/testing-push-notifications-with-xcode-uitests/

My question is: Is it possible to call (directly or indirectly) the UIAppicaltionDelegate's `didReceiveRemoteNotification` from an (UI) `XCTestCase`?

Comment: no but you can use some software to send push notification with out implementation on server

Comment: can you provide further information about your suggestion?

Comment: It will help you to send test push notification with out using server.
https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call functions in your app's code from an **UITest**. UITests run in a separate process and don't have access to your app's functions and methods.

From Apple's Docs:

> UI testing differs from unit testing in fundamental ways. Unit testing
>   enables you to work within your app's scope and allows you to exercise
>   functions and methods with full access to your app's variables and
>   state. UI testing exercises your app's UI in the same way that users
>   do without access to your app's internal methods, functions, and
>   variables. This enables your tests to see the app the same way a user
>   does, exposing UI problems that users encounter.

Directly calling `didReceiveRemoteNotification` from a test is possible in a **UnitTest**. I don't know how your app handles push notifications but if you can test the desired outcome with a unit test that might be a valid alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger events in your app from within a UITest. I have done it before by putting buttons onto my views (a limitation is that I had to add the button(s) to every view I wanted the events happening on).

To make sure you only add the buttons when UITesting, in your `setUp()` function pass in launchArguments by appending elements to the `launchArguments` array.

`launchArguments.append("push_notification_button")`

To access from within the app:

```
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("push_notification_button") {
    // Add button
}
```

Comment: This would work but I not comfortable with test code in my production code.